# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state' => flask + sqlalchemy + many-to-many + WTF SelectMultipleField

Tags: sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-wtforms

I am developing a web application with Flask, WTF, sqlalchemy and bootstrap and I need some help.

I am not able to save a record to the database and am getting the error:

> “AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'”

I have two tables with a many to many relation, as follows:

```
stekstektype = db.Table('stekstektype',
    db.Column('stek_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stek.id')),
    db.Column('stektype_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stektype.id'))
)    

class Stektype(db.Model):
    id           = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner_id     = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    stek_id      = relationship('Stek', secondary = 'stekstektype')
    stektype     = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)  
   
class Stek(db.Model):
    id           = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner_id     = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    stektype_id    = db.relationship('Stektype',secondary='stekstektype')
    name         = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    water        = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    description  = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False) 
    street       = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)  
    number       = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    postalcode   = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)  
    place        = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False) 
    country      = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False) 
    latitude     = db.Column(db.Numeric(10,8), nullable=True)
    longitude    = db.Column(db.Numeric(11,8), nullable=True)
```

I get the above mentioned error when I try to save a record for table “stek” to the database.
The form that I use for creating a “stek” contains a “**SelectMultipleField**”.

```
class StekForm(FlaskForm):
    name          = StringField("Naam van de stek", validators=[DataRequired()])
    water         = StringField("Naam van het water", validators=[DataRequired()])
    description   = TextAreaField("Beschrijving van het water")
    stektypes     = SelectMultipleField(u'Stektypes', coerce=int)
    street        = StringField("Straat", validators=[DataRequired()])
    number        = StringField("Nummer", validators=[DataRequired()])
    postalcode    = StringField("Postcode", validators=[DataRequired()])         
    place         = StringField("Plaats", validators=[DataRequired()])
    country       = StringField("Land", validators=[DataRequired()])
    latitude      = DecimalField("Latitude", validators=[DataRequired()])
    longitude     = DecimalField("Longitude", validators=[DataRequired()])
    saveStek      = SubmitField("Bewaar stek")
```

The view in which I try to save the record is as follows:

```
@stekken.route("/create_stek", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required

def create_stek():

    h1 = Stektype.query.all()        # get all stektypes from db => list with objects
    h2 = []                          # list with stektype names
    h3 = []                          # list with stektype id's
    for x in range(len(h1)):
        h2.append(h1[x].stektype)
        h3.append(h1[x].id)
    h4 = list(zip(h3, h2))           # combined list with choices for the multi select field         
    form = StekForm()
    form.stektypes.choices = h4      # coerce needs to be set at formDef!!!
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_stek  = Stek(owner_id=current_user.id, name=form.name.data, water=form.water.data, description=form.description.data, street=form.street.data, number=form.number.data, postalcode=form.postalcode.data, place=form.place.data, country=form.country.data, latitude=form.latitude.data, longitude=form.longitude.data)
        new_stek2 = Stek(stektype_id=form.stektypes.data)
        db.session.add(new_stek)
        db.session.add(new_stek2)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Stek is created !', category='success')
 
        return redirect(url_for('views.home'))

    return render_template('stekken.html', form=form, user=current_user, key = current_app.config["GOOGLEMAPS_KEY"])
```

The issue regards the line

```
new_stek2 = Stek(stektype_id=form.stektypes.data)
```

I've been working on this for a few days now and can't get it resolved.
Please help!

Comment: `Stek.stektype_id` is a _relationship`, so when creating an new instance a list of `StekType` instances should be provided, but the code in the question is providing a list of integers.  I'd suggest reviewing the [SQLAlchemy docs for many to many relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many), the setup here is very confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll get to work on it later today. I'll study the documentation you refer to (one more time ; looked at it earlier). Which part of the code is confusing?

Comment: `Stektype.stek_id` and `Stek.stektype_id` seem to be a circular relationship - perhaps these relationships should be declared on the association table instead?  For me warnings are raised if I run with warnings enabled (`python -Wall ...`)

Comment: Thanks to your responses I managed to solve the problem in my code. Especially the first notion in the first comment put me on the right track (Stek.stektype_id is a _relationship, so when creating an new instance a list of StekType` instances should be provided, but the code in the question is providing a list of integers)